# Can we assign custom Query Hints to JPA NamedQueries

Tags: database, jpa, db2, openjpa, query-hints

We are required  to append query numbers to each and every query our application executes.

EX:  SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... **QUERYNO 123456**;

OpenJPA supports query hints, but only for specific hints on specific implementations.

```
...
Query q = em.createQuery("select m from Magazine m where ... ");
q.setHint("openjpa.hint.OptimizeResultCount", new Integer(2));
q.setHint("openjpa.FetchPlan.ReadLockMode","WRITE");
List r = q.getResultList();
...
```

But according to the JPA spec, and openjpa "**Invalid hints or hints which can not be processed by a particular database are ignored**. Otherwise, invalid hints will result in an ArgumentException being thrown."
SO specifycing "QUERYNO" as a hint seems to have no impact.

**How do I create a custom Query Hint to specify at runtime?**

...
Query q = em.createQuery("select m from Magazine m where ... ");
q.setHint("**com.me.CustomQueryNoHint**", new Integer(2234));
List r = q.getResultList();
...

Comment: + 1 JPA2 still needs some features out-of-box  ;)

Comment: see the UPDATED ANSWER part in my previous answer.

Comment: @becomputer06  - I think I am not clearly conveying my need. Your latter solution only applies to logging, and is not sent to the database.  QUERYNO is a specific clause, just like WHERE or OPTIMIZE FOR X ROWS.  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.sqlref/db2z_sql_querynoclause.htm

Answer (score 0):

> specifying "QUERYNO" as a hint seems to have no impact.

Correct. Per the doc that you quoted, "QUERYNO" is an invalid hint so it is ignored. The doc is somewhat confusing, but I believe if can be interpreted to support the behavior that you observed. :-)

> How do I create a custom Query Hint to specify at runtime?

That is a much taller task. I don't believe that OpenJPA was designed to allow writing custom query hints.

I thought some more about your actual problem of wanting to append a specific string to EVERY SQL and I don't think it would be very easy to do in OpenJPA. Perhaps you could write a wrapper for your JDBC driver and have that append your string to every SQL?

Comment: Would the wrapper need to be specified in the Web Container's Data Source configuration, or can I telll OpenJPA to use a wrapper with whatver driver it is given by the container?

The problem is that our DBA's only allow a very specific JDBC driver, and manage its configuration on all environments, so unless it can be done purely from the .war side, its an immediate no-go.

Answer (score 0):

Not complete answer but just a pointer...

**QueryCounter**

```
public class QueryCounter {
    private static long COUNTER = 0;

    private static long next() {
        return ++COUNTER;
    }

    private static String getHintValue() {
        return "/*Query No. " + next() + " */";
    }

    public static void setQueryCount(Query query) {
        /* EclipseLink */
        //query.setHint(QueryHints.HINT, getHintValue());
            query.setHint("eclipselink.sql.hint", getHintValue());

        /* OpenJPA + Oracle */
        //query.setHint("openjpa.hint.OracleSelectHint", getQueryHint());

        /* OpenJPA + MySQL */
        //query.setHint("openjpa.hint.MySQLSelectHin", getQueryHint());
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Organization sun = new Organization("Sun");
        em.persist(sun);
        tx.commit();
        Assert.assertNotNull(sun.getEntityId());

        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT org.entityId FROM Organization org WHERE org.entityId = " + sun.getEntityId());
        QueryCounter.setQueryCount(query);
        query.getResultList();

        /*ServerSession does NOT log ReadObjectQuery??*/
        query = em.createQuery("SELECT org FROM Organization org WHERE org.entityId = " + sun.getEntityId());
        QueryCounter.setQueryCount(query);
        query.getResultList();

        query = em.createQuery("SELECT org.entityId FROM Organization org WHERE org.entityId = " + sun.getEntityId());
        QueryCounter.setQueryCount(query);
        query.getResultList();
```

**Console**

```
[EL Finest]: 2010-11-20 19:06:16.45--UnitOfWork(717879615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query ReportQuery(referenceClass=Organization sql="SELECT entity_id FROM organization_tt WHERE (entity_id = ?)")
[EL Fine]: 2010-11-20 19:06:16.475--ServerSession(699542937)--Connection(1949550475)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT /*Query No. 1 */ entity_id FROM organization_tt WHERE (entity_id = ?)
    bind => [1]
[EL Finest]: 2010-11-20 19:06:23.372--UnitOfWork(717879615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query ReadObjectQuery(referenceClass=Organization sql="SELECT entity_id, name FROM organization_tt WHERE (entity_id = ?)")
[EL Finest]: 2010-11-20 19:06:35.916--UnitOfWork(717879615)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query ReportQuery(referenceClass=Organization sql="SELECT entity_id FROM organization_tt WHERE (entity_id = ?)")
[EL Fine]: 2010-11-20 19:06:35.92--ServerSession(699542937)--Connection(1949550475)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT /*Query No. 3 */ entity_id FROM organization_tt WHERE (entity_id = ?)
    bind => [1]
```

OpenJPA has similar concept [1.8.7. Database-Specific Hints](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.0.1/apache-openjpa-2.0.1/docs/manual/jpa_overview_query.html#d0e6955).
See if these specific hints can solve your purpose.

## **UPDATED ANSWER**

@Eddie, see if this can help you...........

**CustomLogFactory**

```
    public class MyLogFactory extends org.apache.openjpa.lib.log.LogFactoryImpl {

    /* copied from LogFactoryImpl.NEWLINE */
    private static final String NEWLINE = J2DoPrivHelper.getLineSeparator();

    private boolean sqlLogger;

    @Override
    public Log getLog(String channel) {
        if("openjpa.jdbc.SQL".equals(channel)) { // OR equalsIgnoreCase(channel) ??? 
            sqlLogger = true;
        }
        return super.getLog(channel);
    }

    @Override
    protected LogImpl newLogImpl() {
        if(sqlLogger) {
            sqlLogger = false; /* once an SQL Logger is created, we dont't need any more instances */
            return new LogImpl() {
                private long sqlCounter = 0;

                @Override
                protected String formatMessage(short level, String message, Throwable t) {
                    if(isSQLString(message)) {
                        StringBuffer formattedMessage = new StringBuffer(super.formatMessage(level, message, t));
                        StringBuffer queryNo = new StringBuffer();
                        queryNo.append("  [Query # ").append(++sqlCounter).append("]").append(NEWLINE);
                        formattedMessage.delete(formattedMessage.length() - NEWLINE.length(), formattedMessage.length());
                        formattedMessage.append(queryNo);
                        return formattedMessage.toString();
                    }
                    return super.formatMessage(level, message, t);
                }

                /* just a sample implementation; checks whether message contains the word "executing"
                 * more concrete implementation should check the message for SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT INTO, ALTER.... clauses */
                private boolean isSQLString(String message) {
                    if(message.contains("executing")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            };
        }
        return super.newLogImpl();
    }

}
```

**peristence.xml**

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="org.opensource.logger.MyLogFactory(DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE)"/>
```

**Test**

```
EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default").createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("Bond-OO7");
person.setAge(22);
em.persist(person);
tx.commit();
em.close();
```

**Console**

```
............
2084  default  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 346613126, conn 1551158018> executing prepstmnt 556472773 SELECT SEQUENCE_OWNER AS SEQUENCE_SCHEMA, SEQUENCE_NAME FROM ALL_SEQUENCES  [Query # 1]
2136  default  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 346613126, conn 1551158018> [52 ms] spent
2305  default  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 346613126, conn 2026561073> executing prepstmnt 6637010 INSERT INTO Person (id, age, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?) [params=?, ?, ?]  [Query # 2]
2306  default  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 346613126, conn 2026561073> [1 ms] spent
............
```

## [Reference](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/apache-openjpa-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT/docs/manual/ref_guide_logging_custom.html)

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like you are just adding comments between /* */ which for OpenJPA can be leverage using the OracleHint.
However, QUERYNO is not a comment, but a DB2 query clause, it must be at the end of statements and outside of comment blocks. 
And as the documentation you point to even suggests, for OpenJPA the hints are only used for Oracle and MySQL. For my DB2 dictionary  either hint string is simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use JPQL and try to force vendor-specific stuff into the query, have you considered writing a native query that is mapped to an entity return type?

```
em.createNativeQuery(YOUR_DB2_NATIVE_SQL_QUERY_STRING, Magazine.class)
```

It will be more work for you since your native query needs to select column values that match up with the mapped columns in the entity class, but it should work. When you use native SQL the query engine must not parse and interpret vendor-specific
SQL, so your DB2-specific clause at the end should be passed through to the underlying database at runtime.